# Centering a div container which is next to a second div container?

Tags: html, css, center

I've a div container which is named headline. In this div there are two elements, a menu bar of type unordered list and a div container. I'll centering horizontally the menu bar, the other div container should dock on the right display side with a margin of 5%. How I can do this, has someone an idea?

Okay here is my litte example from **jsfiddle**: http://jsfiddle.net/nchm3gyj/

**HTML**

```
<div class="headline">
        <ul class="navbar">
            <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Team</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Info</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Downloads</a></li>
        </ul>

        <img class="facebook" src="" />
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
* {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

.headline {
  height: 60px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: black;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.headline .navbar{
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;

  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-right: 10px;

  float: left;
  height: 60px;
  width: auto;
  background-color: yellow;
  list-style: none;
}

.headline .navbar li{
  display: inline;
} 

.headline .navbar li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  line-height: 60px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-right: 10px;
}

.headline .facebook {
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  margin-right: 5%;
  float: right;
}


#clear {
  clear: both;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want your navigation bar centered in the parent block, here is one way of doing it.

Apply  `display: inline-block` to the `.navbar` and `text-align: center` to `.headline`.

Assuming that you want the navigation bar centered with respect to the full
width of the parent block, you need to take the image out of the content flow.
You can do this by applying `position: absolute` to the `.facebook` element.

```css
.headline {
  height: 60px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: black;
  margin-top: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
}

.headline .navbar{
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;

  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-right: 10px;

  height: 60px;
  width: auto;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: yellow;
  list-style: none;
}

.headline .navbar li{
  display: inline;
} 

.headline .navbar li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  line-height: 60px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-right: 10px;
}

.headline .facebook {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 5%;
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
}
```

```html
<div class="headline">
        <ul class="navbar">
            <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Team</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Info</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Downloads</a></li>
        </ul>

        <img class="facebook" src="http://placehold.it/60x60" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm a bit unsure of what you're trying to do, is this it? Applied `text-align: center` to `.headline` and `display: inline-block` to `.navbar` then `position: absolute` to `.facebook`?

http://jsfiddle.net/nchm3gyj/42/

Comment: Sry, no this wasn't my question. I'll centering the navigation bar in the middle of the screen.

Answer (score 0):

I think you might need to `position: absolute` the facebook image and `display: inline-block` your menu bar (being centered by the `.headline`):

http://jsfiddle.net/nchm3gyj/32/